# Maximal ideal space of the $n$-dimensional ball algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $B_n \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be the $n$-dimensional open ball of radius $1$ centered at the origin. Let $A$ be the set consisting of holomorphic functions in $B_n$ which are continuous in $\overline{B_n}$, then $A$ is a Banach space with the sup-norm and pointwise operations. Let $M$ be the maximal ideal space of $A$, that is, $M$ is the set of non-trivial linear multiplicative functionals in $A$.

I want to prove that $M$ and $\overline{B_n}$ are homeomorphic via point-evaluations. In other words, I want to prove that the map $F: \overline{B_n} \longrightarrow M$ defined by $F(x)(\varphi)=\varphi(x)$ is an homeomorphism. Of course, in order to do so the first step is to prove that $F$ is a bijective function. Clearly $F$ is injective. My idea to prove surjectivity was the following: take any $\varphi \in M$ and let $p(z)=\sum_{|\alpha|=0}^{n}{c_{\alpha} z^{\alpha}}$ be a polynomial (here we're using the multi-index notation). For each $i, 1 \leq i \leq n$, let $f_i:\overline{B_n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be the map defined by $f_{i}(z)=z_i$, then we can write $p=\sum_{|\alpha|=0}^{n}{c_{\alpha} f^{\alpha}}$, where $f=(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$. Therefore, since $\varphi \in M$ we have that
$$
\varphi(p)=\sum_{|\alpha|=0}^{n}{c_{\alpha} \varphi(f)^{\alpha}}=p(\varphi(f))
$$
therefore, if I could prove that $\varphi(f)=(\varphi(f_1),\ldots,\varphi(f_n))$ is in $\overline{B_n}$ I would be done proving the surjectivity (since polynomials are dense in $A$). Of course, I can see that $|\varphi(f_i)| \leq 1$ but I don't see why would we have that $|\varphi(f)| \leq 1$.

Any suggestion in order to prove that $|\varphi(f)| \leq 1$?  Or, if my approach is wrong I would appreciate any hint.

In advance thank you very much.

Comment: Idea: Prove the result with $B_n$ replaced by the polydisc $D_n:=\{ z: |z_i|<1\}$, where your argument goes through (I think), and then show that $\bar{D}_n$ and $\bar{B}_n$ (as well as their corresponding algebras of continuous functions) are homeomorphic.

Comment: On second thought, ignore my last comment: For this to work, we'd need $B_n$ and $D_n$ to be biholomorphic (to preserve the corresponding algebras of analytic functions), and this seems to be false.

Comment: @Jose27 it was a good idea though :), maybe my approach is just wrong but I'm out of ideas for the moment.

Comment: Is it possible that $B_n$ is the $n$-dimensional polydisc instead of the usual unit ball? Because if $B_n$ is the polydisc your argument holds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take $\phi \in M, \phi(f_j)=w_j$ where $f_j(z)=z_j$ and assume $w=(w_j)$ is not in $\overline{B_n}$ so $\|w\|_2^2=c > 1$ and clearly
$$
\phi\left(\sum \bar w_j f_j\right)=\|w\|_2^2=c.
$$
But
$$
\left|\phi\left(\sum \bar w_j f_j\right)\right| \le \max_{\|z\|_2 \le 1} \left|\sum (\bar w_j f_j)(z)\right|=\max_{\|z\|_2 \le 1} |\sum \bar w_j z_j| \le (\|w\|_2^2)^{1/2}
$$ by Cauchy-Schwarz, hence $c \le \sqrt c$ which contradicts $c>1$.

This shows that for every $\phi \in M$ we have $(\phi(f_j))=(w_j) \in \overline{B_n}$ and from here it easily follows that $\phi$ is the evaluation at $w=(w_j)$ and we are done!

Comment: Of course, it didn't occur to me, thank you very much! :)

Comment: happy to help - same proof works for numerous compacts $K$ (essentially you need that if $z \in \mathbb C^n$ st $|P(z)| \le \sup_{w \in K}|P(w)|$ for every polynomial (or entire) $P$ then $ z\in K$; these sets are called polynomially convex and for them the proof above goes through to show that $A(K)$ (analytic in the interior of $K$ and continuous on $K$) has only pointwise evaluation spectrum

Comment: interesting! I just learned something new today :), I just started to learn the basics about operator algebras so it's good to getting to know that kind of tricks. Again thank you!